# Is there a stochastic AdaBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, boosting, adaboost

In sklearn, the AdaBoostClassifier and AdaBoostRegressor classes do not have the subsample and max_features parameters, which are responsible for the stochastic approach to building a boosting model. Question: is it possible to build stochastic adaptive boosting at all?